# Outlook 2016 hyperlinks not working in all browsers

Tags: microsoft-outlook, browser, hyperlink, microsoft-office-2016

I have a user (in a company of 80+) that seems unable to open hyperlinks from Outlook 2016.

The message we get is:

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator

Which is not true, we've tried changing browsers and checked the Registry and the .html is set to htmlfile

- OS W10
- App: Office 2016 (O365)
- System: Lenovo
- RAM:16GB
- Browsers: IE, Edge, Firefox, Chrome (all latest variants)

Tried the W7 quickfix download (couldn't hurt) but didn't work.

Have reinstalled chrome so we can assign IE as default browser (this apparently can cause the issue if you use flash) Has made no change.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "official fix" [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310049/hyperlinks-are-not-working-in-outlook)" which does not support Windows 10. Therefore, in your case, follow the instructions below:

1. Create a new text with the text below and save it:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html]
   @="htmlfile"
   "Content Type"="text/html"
   "PerceivedType"="text"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm]
   @="htmlfile"
   "Content Type"="text/html"
   "PerceivedType"="text"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.shtm]
   @="htmlfile"
   "Content Type"="text/html"
   "PerceivedType"="text"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.shtml]
   @="htmlfile"
   "Content Type"="text/html"
   "PerceivedType"="text"

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile\shell\open\command]
   @="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IEXPLORE.EXE\" -nohome"\
   ```
2. Change the extension from `.txt` to `.reg` and execute.

That's it.

(Source [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2013-email-links-arent-working/7122799b-798e-4439-8108-69fa86900a16))